# CSS UL List tabs issue

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have created the following

[image]

And I don't know how to fix the spacing between the tabs.

Maybe the solution is extrimply simple but I cannot figure it out.

I have try several methods but I cannot find out a solution.

Any idea please for what is wrong with that ?

Here you can find the code : http://jsfiddle.net/SFw6V/

Comment: Instead of showing us those useless screenshots, show a http://jsfiddle.net example illustrating your problem in action.

Comment: Also, include your CSS as text, not as picture. Text can be copied, pasted and tested, pictures not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a margin because there is a whitespace character (space, ) between them:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li data-tab="#tab1">
        Tab 1
    </li><li data-tab="#tab2"> <!-- remove spaces -->
        Tab 2
    </li><li data-tab="#tab3"> <!-- remove spaces -->
        Tab 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SFw6V/1/

Comment: Thanks !!! That solved my problem. I couldn't imagine the issue !!! I will mark your answer as a solution in a minute

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in **tabs li** class

**Problem:**
  `display:inline-block` add extra margin to right

**Two Solutions:**

1. `display:block` & `float:left`
2. `margin-right:-4px;`

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/SFw6V/2/

*Better explained & different solutions:* http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/